IRF of consumption to negative productivity shock
Should the IRF of consumption to negative productivity shock be negative or positive? I would think negative but I am little bit confused because IRF is a set of partial derivatives correct? Then, if $\partial e_t$ <0 and since shock decreases consumption, $\partial C_t <0$, so, $\partial C_t/ \partial e_t$ have to be > 0. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Please don't mess with the round d symbol.
You are using it alone as a epsilon change on each variables, but $\partial C_t/\partial e_t$ represents a partial differentiation.
And basically, there's nothing wrong with what you've said.
In general, we could think the effect of productivity shock on consumption is positive, i.e. $\partial C_t/\partial e_t > 0$ as you have mentioned.
What does this mean? When $e_t$ increases (or decreases) a small amount, $C_t$ will increase (or decrease).
So yes. If you do an exercise of negative productivity shock, the consumption will decrease and the IRF will be negative since $\partial C_t/\partial e_t > 0$.
